# Bootstrap modal for edit not openning. ASP.Net-MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I need to make a Modal for editing a player, and I made one, but whenever I click button "Change" it doesen't open my modal. I don't know where am I supposed to send the right ID
this is my jquery

```
var data= 0;
$('.btnEdit').click(function () {
    $('#myModalEdit').modal("show");

});

$('#myModalEdit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    data= button.data("playerId");

});
```

To be precise, when I click Change it does enter the first function, but doesn't open modal. I would really need help. If you need more info, please write what, and I will post it.

Modal code:

```
 <!--Modal-->
        <div id="myModalEdit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Ucinak igraca</h4>
                    </div>
                   @Html.HiddenFor(Model => item.IgracId)
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Model => item.ImeIPrezime)<br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(Model => item.OdigraneMinute)<br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(Model => item.PostignutiGolovi)<br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(Model => item.ZutiKarton)<br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(Model => item.CrveniKarton)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.ImeIPrezime)<br />

                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => item.OdigraneMinute)<br />

                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => item.PostignutiGolovi)<br />

                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => item.ZutiKarton)<br />

                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => item.CrveniKarton)
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                        <div id="greska"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="align-content:center">
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="sacuvaj">Sacuvaj</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primar" data-dismiss="modal" id="odustani">Odustani</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Modal-->
```

Button code:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-igracId="@item.playerId" id="Edit" data-target="#myModalEdit" data-toggle="modal">Izmjeni</button>
```

Comment: did you get any error inconsole

Comment: When I put a console log in first function it wrote the string without error, when I put console log in the bottom one, it doesn't write anything

Comment: was modal opening before adding "show.bs.modal"  event ...||   could you try removeing   data= button.data("playerId"); for testing

Comment: No, I removed it, still nothing

Comment: Could you  show your modal code and button code

Comment: I made and edit up.

Comment: make below changes ,tell if it works

Answer (score 0):

Could you please Add class  "btnEdit" to your Button 
like this

```
class="btn btn-primary btnEdit"
```

Your button is missing the class btnEdit so related click event not getting executed
replaace

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-igracId="@item.playerId" id="Edit" data-target="#myModalEdit" data-toggle="modal">Izmjeni</button>
```

with

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnEdit" data-igracId="@item.playerId" id="Edit" data-target="#myModalEdit" data-toggle="modal">Izmjeni</button>
```

And make sure  script  gets exexutes html rendering done

Sometimes when dynamic html is rendered events are not mapped

```
if its case ADD  onclick="$('#myModalEdit').modal('show');"  to you BUTTON
```